# MVT and natural log question

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that $r>0$ and $r\leq x\leq y$ $\implies$ $\ln y - \ln x \leq \frac{y-x}{r}$ but I'm not sure how to get started. Could this have something to do with the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: The left hand side is negative and the right hand side is positive. Double check, because surely that is not what you want.

Comment: My mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: Now this is immediate from the mean value theorem.

Comment: Could you help me get started? This is my first analysis course and these things don't come particularly easy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

$\ln x$ is continuous and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. $0<r\leq x \leq y$, so $[x,y]\subset(0,\infty)$, hence the MVT applies. Then there is a $c\in(x,y)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$. This is $\frac{1}{c}=\frac{\ln y - \ln x}{y-x}$. Then $\frac{y-x}{c}=\ln y - \ln x$. Since $r\leq x \leq y$ and $c\in(x,y)$, $r\leq c$. Thus $\frac{y-x}{c}\leq\frac{y-x}{r}$ and so $\frac{y-x}{r}\geq \ln y - \ln x$.